# ResultSet returns only last row into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, resultset

I have done enough searches to solve my problem which i have done partly but there's this one bug that keeps disturbing me.I am trying to fetch data from a database based on a condition.I have a table 'user_branch' with a foreign key column branchID which is supposed to fetch the coresponding branchNames in another table 'branches' and I am supposed to display the results into a JTable.When i do System.out.println i get all my results but it returns only the last row when i display in a JTable(branchJTable).This is the code i am using

```
 int row = user2BAssignedJTable.getSelectedRow();
    assignUserID.setText(user2BAssignedJTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
    user2BAssignedField.setText(user2BAssignedJTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());

    try {

        String userBrQry = "SELECT branchID FROM user_branch WHERE userID IN(?) ";
        String brQ = "SELECT branchName FROM branches WHERE branchID IN(%s) ";

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(userBrQry);
        pstmt.setString(1, assignUserID.getText());
        results = pstmt.executeQuery();

        results.last();
        int nRows = results.getRow();
        results.beforeFirst();

        while (results.next()) {
            String branchIDS = results.getString("branchID");

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
                builder.append("?");
                if (i + 1 < nRows) {
                    builder.append(",");
                }
            }
            brQ = String.format(brQ, builder.toString());
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(brQ);
            for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
                ps.setString(i + 1, branchIDS);
            }
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            //branchJTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));                

            javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel model = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Branch Name"});
            branchJTable.setModel(model);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String branchname = rs.getString("branchName");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{branchname});                  

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Forget about the first 3 rows as it is a another JTable event i use to get the userID to use as a condition for getting a particular user's branches assigned to him.
The branches assigned to a user is dynamic hence using StringBuilder.
I am supposed to display the results into another JTable called branchJTable which only displays the last row.Any HELP would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, I think you should declare the JTable

```
javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel model = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Branch Name"});
branchJTable.setModel(model);
```

before your first loop -

i.e. before `while (results.next()) {` in your code.

Otherwise in loop, for each loop execution,

the JTable Model is initialising and you are getting the last inserted row in Jtable.